# Reverse proxy with nginx on the same port

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm more a programmer than a server admin, so the question might seem trivial to some, but I can't get my nginx reverse proxy to forward my requests to the right server... First, here's my config file (in sites-available, with a symlink in sites-enabled)

```
upstream nodejs1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream nodejs2 {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
    server_name nodejs_proxy;
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nodejs.log;
    location /otherlocation/ {
            rewrite /otherlocation/(.*) /$1 break;
            proxy_pass      http://nodejs1/;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://nodejs2/;
            proxy_redirect  off;
            proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
    }
}
```

So if I try to access `http://myserver.com/`, everything works fine and I'm redirected on port 3001. However, if I try to access `http://myserver.com/otherlocation/`, I'm also redirected to port 3001 (so I get a 404).

Is there something in the above snippet I don't do correctly to be redirected to the right server when I try to access `http://myserver.com/otherlocation/`?

Thank you

PS : myserver.com is a temporary domain that's prone to change multiple times (dev, pre-prod, prod) so that's why I'm trying to write something what will work on all environments

Comment: Try `location ^~ /otherlocation/ {` to ensure that location searching is stopped if otherlocation is found

Comment: Thanks, I added it but it did not change anything :/

Comment: Ooooh, I just saw that rewrite rule. You are rewriting everything from /otherlocation/ back to /. I had already written a big answer when I saw this, so I'll publish it anyway. It may help you in the future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should check that the right server is handling the request and debug what's most important. In your nginx.conf file (not in sites-enabled) inside the `http` block place this

```
log_format mcombined '$server_name - $host - $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';
```

The above is the default [log format](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLogModule#log_format) of nginx with the addition of `$server_name` and `$host`. You may add any [variable](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#Variables) you think may be useful.

Then change your sites-enabled conf to use this log format:

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/nodejs.log mcombined;
```

**But the real problem is this:** Inside your `/otherlocation/` block, you have a rewrite rule that rewrites everything to `/`, so when the requests come to the /otherlocation/ block, they are redirected to `/`.

So your final sites-enabled conf will look like this:

```
upstream nodejs1 {
  server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

upstream nodejs2 {
  server 127.0.0.1:3001;
}

server {
  server_name nodejs_proxy;
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/nodejs.log mcombined;
  location ^~ /otherlocation/ {
        proxy_pass      http://nodejs1/;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
  }

  location / {
        proxy_pass      http://nodejs2/;
        proxy_redirect  off;
        proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice response! However, it did not actually solve the problem. I solved it by reloading nginx configurations and adding ~* before my location, similar to what you suggested in a comment to my original post. I kept the rewrite rule and it still worked for me!

But the logging advice was very useful, thank you for this!